# What are valid country codes while searching for Available Numbers in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hi I am trying to fetch the available countries in Twilio. For example for US I use below API: 
Local.reader("US").setVoiceEnabled(true).setSmsEnabled(true).  For United Kingdom, I use Local.reader("GB").setVoiceEnabled(true).setSmsEnabled(true).  How can I get the list of valid country codes.  I am unable to find it in Twilio API docs. 
Many Thanks
shekup

Answer (score 1):

I believe it follows the `ISO country code`.
You can find more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Twilio's API is open source, if you're interested you can read the code on GitHub.

For example in this page https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AvailablePhoneNumberCountry/NationalList.php you can see the comment:

`* @param string $countryCode The ISO Country code to lookup phone numbers for.`